Where is it specified the path to look for kernel.json, to select the jupyter kernel in anaconda?
I am launching an Anconda prompt from a Windows shortcut.
Its target is %windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" %PYTHONDIR%\Scripts\activate.bat root,
with PYTHONDIR=C:\Users\User1\Anaconda\.
At the prompt I get
(base) C:\Users\User1\Documents> jupyter kernelspec list
[ListKernelSpecs] WARNING | Config option `kernel_spec_manager_class` not recognized by `ListKernelSpecs`.
Available kernels:
  python3    C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\python3

(base) C:\Users\User1\Documents>

In the corresponding C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\python3\kernel.json (K1) I have
{
 "argv": [
  "C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\appls_mydocs\\anaconda3\\python.exe",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "Python 3",
 "language": "python"
}

And in another C:\Users\User1\Anaconda\share\jupyter\kernels\python3\kernel.json (K2) I have
{
 "argv": [
  "C:/Users/User1/Anaconda\\python.exe",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "Python 3",
 "language": "python"
}

Where is it stated which kernel.json to use to select the jupyter kernel (in this case, K1)?
I would actually mean to use K2, whenever I launch an Anaconda prompt in that same directory.
If I rename K1 to something else, and lanuch another Anaconda prompt, it points to K2, so there seems to be a sequence of directories as a search path where to look.

Answer is here.

Jupyter uses a search path to find installable data files, such as
kernelspecs and notebook extensions. When searching for a resource,
the code will search the search path starting at the first directory
until it finds where the resource is contained.
Each category of file is in a subdirectory of each directory of the
search path. For example, kernel specs are in kernels subdirectories.

For Windows this is:

JUPYTER_DATA_DIR or (if not set) %APPDATA%\jupyter
{sys.prefix}/share/jupyter/
%PROGRAMDATA\jupyter

So in my case, I would have to set JUPYTER_DATA_DIR in the launcher, to avoid tampering with files in %APPDATA%\jupyter.
